# Angular JS know what is Triggered with a Checkbox Image and Radio Button Image

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs, checkbox, model

I have something like this

I did not use input type checkbox rather, I used images. 
If the checkbox is unchecked li will not have a class "checked"

```
<li ng-model="FirstCheckBox">



<div>Check1</div>



</li>
```

but if the checkbox is checked li will have a class "checked"

```
<li ng-model="FirstCheckBox" class="checked">                                                                                                                                               
<div>Check1</div>                                                                   
</li>
```

My concern is what is the proper way to set the $scope.FirstCheckBox to true or false based on it's li having a class "checked"

Also I am not sure if the ng-model is supposed to be at the li

Comment: what a problem with using input checkbox?

Comment: I am also trying to avoid doing something like model.closest li then if that li has this class it will set the model to true.

Comment: @monkeyinsight because I am working with designers so we prefer to use images to make the UI more presentable

Comment: you can use js libraries for that, that will transform checkboxes into images like this one http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/

Comment: good one, but sorry we're not allowed to use jquery for this project, we have some complications and stuff. thanks tho we could use that in other projects

Comment: Well, regarding this, i guess it will be tricky for to get it worked, you need to parse html DOM after initialization page and find checked sections which you will add then to model. Any possibility to insert data in model before page load?

Comment: You could use a hidden checkbox with ng-model, and then use ng-class on the li to reflect the model state. ng-model IS meant to be used on inputs, not <li>.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that approach tho, I'm thinking of using the $watch of angular,  anyways, thanks man!

Comment: @aet horay! I'm going to try that right now, thanks! makes a lot of sense :D

Answer (score 0):

If any events are being triggered then it can be done by passing $event and reading the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass to dynamically change the css.

try this,

In html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>{{greetings}} Plunker!</h1>

    <div ng-class="selectCss">
        <span ng-click="toggle(selectCss)">Click me to change css</span>
    </div>




  </body>

</html>
```

In app.js file,

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',function(scope){
  scope.greetings='hello';


   scope.selectCss='unchecked';
    scope.toggle=function(selectCss){

        if(selectCss==='checked'){

            scope.selectCss='unchecked';
        }else{

         scope.selectCss='checked';
        }
    }

 }])
```

In style.css,

```
.unchecked{
  background-color:yellow;

}
.checked{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1NE3PNwADkFZUGsvDKdV?p=preview).

Hope this answers your query :)